# Color where shapes overlap R

Tags: r

Is it possible to have two transparent shapes overlap but have it be a single color and not become a darker shade.

```
library(ggplot2, "maps")
states<-map_data("state")
scenario<-subset(states, region %in% c("arizona", "new mexico", "texas", "oklahoma", 
          "kansas", "missouri", "louisiana", "arkansas", "colorado", "nebraska"))

Locations<-read.csv("FRIENDLY.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

map<-ggplot(data = scenario) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "palegreen", color = "black") +
  coord_fixed(1.3)

map +
  geom_point(data= Locations, aes(x = LONG, y = LAT), fill = "black", size=64, alpha=I(0.2))
```

[[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: Are you talking about the points becoming darker when they overlap each other, or when they overlap the map, or both?

Comment: I am talking about when the points overlap each other. I want to be able to see the map but have the points be one shade of grey.

Comment: If you want to be able to specify the colour based on the overlap then you probably need to use point geometries instead of just size 64 points on the map. You can then buffer the points and calculate the intersections of the circles.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just use points with no fill and `shape = 1`, which is a hollow point with only the edge?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
#> Warning: package 'maps' was built under R version 3.5.1
scenario <- subset(map_data("state"), region %in% c(
  "arizona", "new mexico", "texas", "oklahoma",
  "kansas", "missouri", "louisiana", "arkansas", "colorado", "nebraska"
))
set.seed(12345)
locations <- data.frame(
  LONG = runif(10, -115, -90),
  LAT = runif(10, 25, 40)
)

ggplot(data = scenario) +
  geom_polygon(
    mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
    fill = "palegreen",
    color = "black"
    ) +
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  geom_point(
    data = locations,
    mapping = aes(x = LONG, y = LAT),
    fill = NA,
    size = 64,
    shape = 1
    )
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).